# How to call secure dotnet core web api inside Bot?

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I have created a Microsoft Bot inheriting TeamsActivityHandler for Messaging Extension in Teams in dotnetcore.
Inside the OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync method, I am trying to call a secure API that is hosted locally using HttpClient. I am calling this to populate a choiceSet in my Adaptive Card that will be invoked.
I am getting error in Teams UI whenever I try to invoke a messaging extension,

> "Unable to reach app" - 502 error code

This secure api is an async method. As I couldn't debug the bot code, I couldn't figure out the exact error or what am I missing in some articles, I can see the example for unsecure Api's but nothing much regarding Secure APIs.
Can anyone please suggest an approach?

Comment: Share your required code snippet how you are calling the `endpoint` and how is your `API` is? So that it can be reproducible or can be tested.

Comment: It's an API to get bearer token from AAD, which I maybe can't share it here. However,  can anyone share an example to call an async API with Bearer token authorization header.

Comment: You can try like this [code sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/faridkiron/aL6ckgmu/1/). `Note:` Just copy the code snippet and run on your environment. That's `js fiddle` so `C#` wouldn't be executed there.

Comment: @MaheSHYU - You can add a [Authorize] attribute on your API and call the API with proper header with authentication token.

Comment: Yes that has resolved the issue. I have to look into the SSO to get the token

Comment: Does the the sample help you to get resolve your issue?